# Selection of the range of hours for a given day of the week

Tags: angular

I have written a schedule in which I would like to select time ranges for a given day of the week. In addition, I have a check-box added, where I would like it to set me up all day, and after unchecking it, I can choose the range of hours myself. Please help

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fnk2ma?fbclid=IwAR0U_uXcEvqauMcCCj9_cLbBP_uJojRCDQ6Umumbf6KHLBltjtkzmkhwAE0&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've taken your stackblitz script and tweaked it a bit so it has the desired behavior.

The steps I've taken include:

- Created a Row interface to avoid using *any* types. One of the key points in Typescript.
- Simplified the data structure -> now there is one instead of two.
- Changed the cell click function -> took out the *active* class toggle and now only work with the cell value. In the HTML, there is a *ngClass* directive that toggles the *active* class if the cell value is 1.
- Added a function to toggle the entire row.
- Fixed the *input* id and *label* for tags so they're not the same in the entire array and thus if you pressed any *label*, it would toggle only the first row.

We could go even further and remove the active field from the rows, but it does simplify the readiness.

**Here you go**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cehxvw?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: How can I do that, after clicking the "save" button, extracting information, for example, for Monday hours: {from: '00: 00 ', to: '23: 00'} or
for Tuesday {from: '01: 00 ', to: '03: 00'} {from: '11: 00 ', to: '13: 00'} etc https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n7m3f6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: That would be easier if you typed the items differently. Probably you should have an interface like Col: { toggled, from, to }. Then you would have to iterate through all entries a group them by toggled. Then you would print the from of the first group and the to of the last group.

Comment: I do not know how to create a structure to obtain such information. Will you help me ?

Comment: I don't have the availability to code it from scratch atm. It would be easier to discuss anything you might achieve. Trust me, you'll learn a ton more by doing.

Comment: Hey, I thought it over and I would like the interface I added in stackblitz. I added a new field and an example for it. But that's it, can you tell me how to get this effect?https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-n7m3f6?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts